# Browser support for numeric font-weight

Tags: fonts, cross-browser, css

When was full support for **numeric** font-weight added to each browser? Specifically: IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari, Android Browser.

I know all browsers support `bold` and `normal`, but I've been unable to find a up-to-date list of browsers that fully support **numeric** values for the CSS font-weight property. The only info I found was [Font-weight is still broken](http://clagnut.com/blog/2228). It shows most browsers at the time failing to render numeric weights correctly but it's from 2009 before IE8 was even released.

Example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }
.light { font-weight:300 }
.normal { font-weight:400 }
.bold { font-weight:700 }
</style>
```

Comment: Here is a nice article to read: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/

Comment: I've read it. I'm looking for the specific versions when support was added. Similar to how caniuse.com shows browser support.

Comment: Oh OK... I did some googling didn't find anything but this article http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-weight#compatibilitysection. But nothing like caniuse. Guess I can't help on this one.

Comment: Thanks, that article suggests all browsers have full support but then a commenter notes that that's incorrect. Saying (back in 2008): "I would argue that none of the browsers listed support font-weight to a 'full' standard, as none support the numerical scale. Currently only Firefox 3 and Webkit nightlies support numbers as values of font-weight."

Comment: What is the question, really? The page cited is obscure, as it does not make it clear what really happens in terms of *real* typefaces with different weights versus synthetic bolding. Moreover, the code sample is about `@font-face`, which is rather different; I don't think you can expect to find even a historical browser that supports it but does not support numeric font weights.

Comment: "When was full support for numeric font-weight added to each browser" is the question. How is that unclear? The code sample is just illustrating a use-case and it is one that the article suggest will fail in IE8 (which does support `@font-face`). This type of information is readily available on caniuse.com for tons of CSS properties, but not `font-weight`. So call me crazy but I hoped SO could help find the answer.

Comment: Have you tried using @font-face to load the page than cdn? This way you can load different fonts for their individual properties (light/normal/bold). You have to use font-weight: normal if u do it like this.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the numeric values for font-weight are there since font-weight was supported on each browser... the thing is that all nuances of the weight (all that numeric-scale spectre), depends on the font itself (from the user's machine, or if you've added via @font-face), if the font doesn't have a "semibold", 500 won't do anything.

You can take a look to the specification, there's an explanation of how browsers behave when the *weight* is not present at the font: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness

Hope this can help

Comment: The article I linked to shows that old versions of IE and Firefox did not render the weights correctly despite the different weights being present on the testers machine. The question is, when did each browser fix this (they all have now). Based on all my searches, I've concluded it is not documented anywhere.