# How to reduce the font-weight of an H2 heading inline - best practices

Tags: css, font-size

I have the following text displayed on a website

```
<h2 font-weight="33">H2 Heading which I want thinner</h2>
```

The above doesn't work.

```
<h2><font-weight="33">H2 Heading which I want thinner</font></h2>
```

I know I can use the CSS like so:

```
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

but I have several complex and different internal and external existing css already in place, hence the requirement to override it in-line.

What is the best way to make the H2 tag thinner. I also ask the question because I read that font-weight is depreciated in html5.

Best practices and a solution in line with modern requirements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this it:

```
<h2 style="font-weight: 33">H2 Heading which I want thinner</h2>
```

Comment: could you also perhaps comment though on the fact that apparently this font-weight feature is depreciated in HTML5. Will it no longer work?

Comment: I have not found any information that the font-weight property does not work in html5. I use this property in my projects and have no problems.

Comment: It works now...but have a look at this link. Is the information here incorrect?https://html.com/attributes/font-weight/

Comment: yes, it is. some browsers do not support some of the font-weight property values.

Comment: so does that mean that the answer is not strictly good practice? I want what I use to be supported by all browsers and in keeping with the latest suggestions.

Comment: here's a good answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589841/browser-support-for-numeric-font-weight